# Is autoprefixer active in angular-cli beta 19

Tags: angular-cli, autoprefixer

I hope this is the correct place for this question.  I see that in the angular-cli repo, there now exists code for utilizing the autoprefixer plugin.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autoprefixer
but I don't see it in my copy of beta 19-3.  Is it there, and if so, how do we activate it?

The feature request(s) shows it as finished:
angular-cli/issues/1512
angular-cli/pull/2852

Comment: I experience the exact same Issue here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2852

Answer (score 0):

According to Meligy`s comment on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3123 the autoprefixer changes were merged after 19-3. So they will appear in the next release.